# Getting Compass to add vendor prefixes to animation selectors

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, compass-sass

Can anyone tell me how I can get Compass to add the vendor prefixes to CSS3 animation selectors when it compiles? My config file looks like this.

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "/"
sass_dir = "/"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

output_style = :expanded
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
```

I've tried adding `Compass::BrowserSupport.add_support("animation", "webkit", "moz", "ms")` to it, but it doesn't work.

---

Edit

In response to cimmanon's comment, I wanted to avoid having to repeat every selector like this:

```
.big-wheel {
    left: 77px;
    bottom: 11px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-animation-name: wheels;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-animation-name: wheels;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-animation-name: wheels;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.25s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    animation-name: wheels;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?  Compass doesn't magically inject prefixes wherever it feels like.  Prefixes are primarily done via [mixins](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/).

Comment: Oh, OK.. Basically I want to avoid having to do the above (added in edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compass does have a built in mixin for [transform](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/)

I don't see mixins for the other items documented on the website.  Compass makes it easy to write your own if you need to using the [`experimental` mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/shared/).

```
.foo {
    @include experimental('animation-name', wheels, webkit, moz, o, ms, not khtml);
    @include experimental('animation-duration', 0.25s, webkit, moz, o, ms, not khtml);
    // alternate way of setting prefixes
    $animation-support: webkit, moz, o, ms, not khtml;
    @include experimental('animation-iteration-count', infinite, $animation-support...);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.foo {
  -webkit-animation-name: wheels;
  -moz-animation-name: wheels;
  -ms-animation-name: wheels;
  -o-animation-name: wheels;
  animation-name: wheels;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -o-animation-duration: 0.25s;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thanks cimmanon. It seems a strange hole in Compass's support. I also came across the vendorize mixin on David Walsh's site which does a similar thing. http://css-tricks.com/redesigning-with-sass/

Comment: What's documented on the website is what's in the stable version of Compass.  There *are* new things in the Sass repository that may be available using the edge version (install via `gem install compass --pre`):  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/transforms/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_animation.scss

Comment: Animations have been added on the master branch - 0.13 has just taken a long time to reach full release. If you aren't comfortable using the alpha (I have been for some time now), you can use the [compass animation plugin](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation) for now.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a library like [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/). Then in your SCSS file you would only have to write a single `include` statement, and Bourbon would generate all the prefixes for you on export.

```
@include transform(translateY(50px));
```

Comment: This isn't what the question requires at all. Transforms are different to animations; Compass has its own transform mixin included as well.